# How to combine the dataset in python as below requirement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, predictive

I have a dataset for which I need to add two new columns to an existing dataframe at the end.

[image: Sample Input Data]

[image: Need to add these two columns to the Sample Input Data]

Comment: Yuo can use a pandas.concat function to concatenate all together, but to be more precise you should explain what kind of machine learning process you are using, there is not enough information right now to give a precise answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ordering of rows of both DataFrames is same, use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with set default index values by `drop=True` in [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.concat([X_test.reset_index(drop=True), dfs], axis=1)
```